# OClif mock method

Tags: javascript, oclif

Let's say I have

```
export class MyCommand {
  async run() {
    this.someCommand();
    ...
  }

  someCommand() {

  }
}
```

I want to write a test for the `run` command but mock out the `someCommand`. How do you do that using the

```
test
  .stdout()
  .command()
  .it('should run the run command', () => {
     // also test that someCommand was called
  })
```